# Django: unicode string gets written to database as non-unicode

Tags: python, django

I have written a basic script that imports several thousand values into a Django database. Here's how it looks like: [link](http://pastebin.com/FDAyYLGs).

Those locations are in Cyrillic letters, and are represented as unicode literals. However, as soon as I save them to the database, they are converted to what seems to be encoded simple strings, in some sort of hex encoding:

```
>>> Region.objects.all()[0].parent
'\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb1\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd1\x81\xd1\x82 \xd0\xa1\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd'
```

Surprisingly, they appear correctly in the admin panel, but I have trouble when trying to use them. How do I store and retrieve them as unicode?

I'm running Django 1.4.0 on top of MySQL, collation set to utf8_bin.

Comment: I'm unsure as to whether one can actually print unicode on the console. Regarding your database, check your database's default encoding, and make sure it's UTF-8. E.g. MySQL usually has some other ascii-based encoding.

Comment: @JosvicZammit Edited for clarity. I can even print the original data just fine, but not the saved field values.

Comment: I think it is because of utf8_bin. It stores unicode data as a binary representation. Try setting collation to `utf8_general_cs` or `utf8_general_ci`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Django/MySQL "bug". See issue [#16052](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16052). It's actually [documented here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/databases/#collation-settings).

Comment: Changing the database-wide collation to `utf8_general_ci` seems to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the data is being returned as a UTF-8 byte string rather than a Unicode string. Try decoding it:

```
>>> x='\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb1\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd1\x81\xd1\x82 \xd0\xa1\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd'
>>> x.decode('utf-8')
u'\u043e\u0431\u043b\u0430\u0441\u0442 \u0421\u043b\u0438\u0432\u0435\u043d'
>>> print x.decode('utf-8')
област Сливен
```

Comment: This seems to work for now; I didn't know this was UTF-8. I'll see if it solves my issues - thanks!